# How to mark a Hyperlink with Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium, hyperlink, href

I'm trying to mark the hyperlink "Edit this page" on this website: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/getting_started/quick/

My Code is:

```
driver.get("https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/getting_started/quick/");
WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Edit this page"));
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        actions.moveToElement(elem)
        .click()
        .keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys("a").keyUp(Keys.CONTROL)
        .build().perform();
```

With this code it will be marked all texts on page. How can i mark only the Hypelink?

Answer (score 1):

Instead you use `Actions`, try using `JavascriptExecutor` by setting the background color of the element:

```
WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Edit this page"));
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].style.backgroundColor='lightblue'", elem);
```

You need following import:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
```

I've tried with following result:
[image: Result]

Comment: Hello frianH, thank you for your answer. You have set the backgound color of the element. I dont know, if it's the same thing with when you mark the Linktext with mouse??? Is this the same thing with something like: keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys("a").keyUp(Keys.CONTROL)

Comment: @MusterTester That's different. But I think if your question is "How to mark a Hyperlink", this is a simple way to achieve. The question is what do you want to achieve next by mark these elements so you have to use the `Actions` method?